# Is it possible to have a name collision with URLEncoder

Tags: java, urlencode

I am using java's URLEncoder to take a user provided string and create a string that is safe to use for filenames. What I'm wondering is it possible for two different strings to be encoded to the same value.

For example, if one string is "ABC%20D" but since % is used as a character to replace special characters is it possible that something like "ABC D" and "ABC%20D" both end up as the same encoded value? Or will the encoder always replace characters like % with something else?

Comment: The fact that you're asking this should start ringing alarm bells in your mind...

Comment: Not a constructive comment, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to encode escape characters using your example input:

```
String result = URLEncoder.encode("ABC%20D", "UTF-8");
System.out.println(result);  //prints ABC%2520D
```

Comment: Right, I saw that for this particular example. I just didn't know if it was possible to have a collision or if it is generally designed so those collisions won't happen.